# How do I specify a different folder for .spacemacs file?

Tags: spacemacs

I want to put my .spacemacs into Github, so I cloned it to a local directory. How to let Emacs use the .spacemacs in that directory instead of from the default ~/.spacemacs?

Comment: I've symlinked `~/.spacemacs` to my version-controlled `.spacemacs` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In much the same way as Emacs loads `~/.emacs.d/init.el` if it can't find a `~/.emacs` file, so does Spacemacs load `~/.spacemacs.d/init.el` if it can't find a `~/.spacemacs` file.

This means you can create a `~/.spacemacs.d` directory and rename the `~/.spacemacs` file to `~/.spacemacs.d/init.el`. Then you put the `~/.spacemacs.d` directory on GitHub, and you're done.

If you have some private layers, you can also move them inside `~/.spacemacs.d/` and manage them in the same repository.

Comment: spacemacs uses already an `init.el` file - but you can nevertheless append the `.spacemacs` file to the `init.el`

Comment: If you're talking about `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, that's the entry point for Spacemacs code (technically Spacemacs is a configuration for Emacs). It loads `~/.spacemacs` (or `~/.spacemacs.d/init.el`), so there's no reason to append `.spacemacs` to `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

Comment: the reason to do that is to simplify storing the spacemacs config inside a git repo

Comment: I can't see how this answer would work. `emacs` looks for `~/.emacs.d/init.el` or `~/.emacs` and only then are the `Spacemacs` configurations therein loaded.

Answer (score 6):

You can symlink your `.spacemacs` file. From a bash prompt:

```
$ ln -s /path/to/your/spacemacs-directory/.spacemacs ~/.spacemacs
```

You might find it easier to symlink the entire directory to a "dot directory," i.e. `~/.spacemacs.d`, in which case you would do this:

```
$ mv /path/to/your/spacemacs-directory/.spacemacs /path/to/your/spacemacs-directory/init.el
$ ln -s /path/to/your/spacemacs-directory ~/.spacemacs.d
```

Comment: thanks, but I am using windows instead of linux

Comment: Depending on your version of Windows, you can do the same using the `mklink` command. Create a directory symbolic link using `mklink /D link target`.